# MVVM Light EventToCommand - Cannot get evnt to trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've read about every answer provided on the forum for EventToCommand and cannot get my event to trigger.  Here are the code snippets making up my problem.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015 community edition.

UserControl declarations:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"


<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:MenuTreeViewModel></vm:MenuTreeViewModel>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<syncfusion:TreeViewAdv x:Name="treeMain" Width="340" Margin="10,0,0,0"    
    ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, Mode=TwoWay,  
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" 
                                VisualStyle="ShinyBlue" FontFamily="Verdana" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="11" Height="768" 
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Visibility="Visible">

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
       <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItemChanged,  
                                  ElementName=treeMain,  Mode=OneWay}" 
                                  PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
   </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

My ViewModel logic:

MenuTreeViewModel code:

```
public void SelectedItemChanged(object sender,  
                                     RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue is Models.MenuTree)
            {
                // This is the Top Level Clients item
                // Nothing needs to be done.
                // clear out Current items of all Model types
                //   MenuTree tree = (MenuTree)e.NewValue;

            }
            if (e.NewValue is Models.Provider)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Provider";
                // Set CurrentProvider to the selected item.
                Dal db = new Dal();
            }
            if (e.NewValue is Models.Batch)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Batch");
            }
            if (e.NewValue is Models.Consumer)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Consumer");
            }
        }
    }
```

I know I must be missing something.  Can someone help?

Thank-you.

Dave K

Comment: I don't think you can bind to a method like this by default.... you need an `ICommand` that runs your method.

Comment: like @Rachel said, you can only bind an `ICommand`. Hence the name, event to *command*.

Answer (score 0):

@Rachel is right

You are using MvvmLight so use the built in relay command.  Put this in your view model and bind to the public property **MyCommand** or whatever you rename it to.

```
public RelayCommand MyCommand 
{ 
  get; 
  private set; 
} 

public MainViewModel() 
{ 
  MyCommand = new RelayCommand( 
    ExecuteMyCommand, 
    () => _canExecuteMyCommand); 
} 

private void ExecuteMyCommand() 
{ 
  // Do something 
}
```

You need to do some reading to make sure you understand this as you should not be using control events for VM related functions in MVVM

take a look [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call methods using EventToCommand, the property should be a command.

You can try the following to make it work

**MenuTreeViewModel.cs**

```
public class MenuTreeViewModel
{
     public ICommand SelectedValueUpdated { get; set; }

     public MenuTreeViewModel()
     {
          SelectedValueUpdated = new SelectedValueUpdated(this);
     }
}
```

**SelectedValueUpdated.cs**

```
class SelectedValueUpdated : ICommand
{
    private MenuTreeViewModel _mvModel;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { }
        remove { }
    }
    public SelectedValueUpdated(MenuTreeViewModel mvModel)
    {
        _mvModel = mvModel;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e = (RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object>)parameter;
        if (e.NewValue is Models.MenuTree)
        {
            // This is the Top Level Clients item
            // Nothing needs to be done.
            // clear out Current items of all Model types
            //   MenuTree tree = (MenuTree)e.NewValue;

        }
        if (e.NewValue is Models.Provider)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Provider";
            // Set CurrentProvider to the selected item.
            Dal db = new Dal();
        }
        if (e.NewValue is Models.Batch)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Batch");
        }
        if (e.NewValue is Models.Consumer)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Consumer");
        }
    }
}
```

**UserControlDeclarations**

```
    <syncfusion:TreeViewAdv x:Name="treeMain" Width="340" Margin="10,0,0,0"    
        ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, Mode=TwoWay,  
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" 
                                    VisualStyle="ShinyBlue" FontFamily="Verdana" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="11" Height="768" 
                                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Visibility="Visible">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
           <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectedValueUpdated,  Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
       </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </syncfusion:TreeViewAdv>
```